# Mutual TLS with SQUID

Tags: squid

We have a use case in which we need to do mutual TLS with an upstream server. Our internal services are using their own certificates, and we would like to use the SQUID proxy as a kind of gateway to which we send requests for the upstream server. The squid proxy will verify the incoming certificate and if correct, replace it by a certificate that is appropriate for the upstream server. I'm wondering whether this is possible with squid. I have been looking into ssl-bump of squid but couldn't get it working.

Has anybody any experience with mutual authentication and squid ?

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No, Eventually we implemented a custom library in our internal services that took care of the mutual TLS.